# Anorm: Escape { for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, playframework, anorm, playframework-2.5

I want to execute query like this:

`SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}'`

But anorm can not prepare the query and raise the parse error.

How to escape the '{' and '}' symbols in SQL text for anorm?

Comment: `jsonb_build_object('a',json_build_array(1,2,3),'b',json_build_array(4,5,6))` see the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: it's a workaround just for the provided example. the problem is to escape the symbols {,} , but not to execute sql above. Any case, thank you.

Comment: try running this instead: `SELECT $safequoting${"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}$safequoting$::json#>>$safe${a,2}$safe$` - I think it is quotes problem, not curve brackets

Answer (score 0):

Update:
the solution is a pretty simple (like [RTFM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):) )

```
SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}'
```

should be

```
SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json->'a'->>2
```

there are no symbols '{', '}' so Anorm is happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values as stings which contain curly braces

Look at this example

```
SELECT '{}'::jsonb;
```

so I replaced it with binding

```
SELECT {empty}::jsonb;
```

And passed this named param on executing the query

```scala
NamedParameter("empty", "{}")
```